# Ajax call is not successfull but firebug net shows Ok

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Below is my code. Firebug shows 200 OK status.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
question: <br> myquestion33<br>
</h1>
<p id = "comments">
comments <br> <br> <br> <br> test<br> test<br>
</p>
Type your comment here
<div id = "newcommentblock">
<p id = "newComment"> </p>
<form id = "foo" name = "commentbox" action = "#" >
<input type = "text" id ="newComment" name = "newComment">
<input type = "submit" value = "post a comment">
</form>
</div>
<p id = "answer">
answer
</p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#foo").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
// $("#newcommentblock").html(&#039;<img src="a.gif"/>&#039;);
request = $.ajax({
url: "getcomment.php",
type: "POST",
timeout:30000,
dataType: "text",
data:{getquestionid: 33
,
getcomment: "test" } ,
});
alert("inside script");
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
//$("#comments").html(response);
});
request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
console.error(
"The following error occured: " +
textStatus, errorThrown
);
});
request.always(function () {
});
console.log("hi inside");
});
});
</script>
```

Now, since database at back end is getting updated with latest values and firebug also shows the Ok status but we can't get inside

```
 request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    //$("#comments").html(response);
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated. thank you

Ok here is my getcomment.php

```
<?php



$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL :(");


$selected = mysql_select_db("place",$dbhandle)
 or die("Could not select akshat :(");







$getcomment=$_POST["getcomment"];
$getquestionid=$_POST["getquestionid"]; 

$pkey=rand();

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO place_comment (sno,comment) VALUES ('$pkey','$getcomment') ")
or die(mysql_error());


$result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO question_comment (q_sno,c_sno) VALUES ('$getquestionid','$pkey') ")
or die(mysql_error());


//fetch tha data from the database
//while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 //  echo " ".$row{'question'}."<br>";
 //  echo "hello";
//}




//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);


?>
```

Comment: please fill this in: *"The following error occured: <a number> <some text>"*

Comment: @KevinB Actually it doesn't enter the error function at all...and it doesn't enter always function also..kind of weird because if its an error it should atleast give error...any suggestions

Comment: @SarathSprakash as in previous comment

Comment: Then you should have an error in your console somewhere. jquery ajax requests don't silently fail without entering the fail callback.

Comment: @user1590595 its working not a problem of client side here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/J3f5U/1/, have you checked your console or may be some other problem in your server side ,please post your php code

Comment: @SarathSprakash I have posted php code in question. Thanks

Comment: @user1590595 your php is fine, try to set the content type with   header ('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded') in your php , just try this

Answer (score 0):

Check syntax in your html returned. I had a similar problem, and a malformed attribute in a tag was doing my application silently fail.